# Finding XML element using name under other parent using XPath only

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get a value from an XML sheet that depends on its name, which has a different parent node. In the example below, let's say I want to pull the value of "b", which is 2. How can I dynamically get a value based on its name with a XML structure like below, using only XPaths? I have no control on the format of the incoming XML, and I have limited functionality to read it, which is why I'd like to stick with XPaths if possible.

```
<Data>
    <Names>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <Name>d</Name>
    </Names>
    <Values>
        <Value>1</Value>
        <Value>2</Value>
        <Value>3</Value>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Values>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find needed node `Name`, count nodes `Name` before and get `Value`on the same position

```
/Data/Values/Value[position() = count(/Data/Names/Name[.="b"]/preceding-sibling::Name)+1]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Just so I understand how it works: it finds the index of the name I'm looking for, then moves up a node (preceding-siblng) and uses the index to find the value.

Comment: `/Data/Names/Name[.="b"]` finds the node and `count(preceding-sibling)+1` right gets the index of `b` in names